# Amazon Athena - Creating external table and ignoring commas enclosed in quotes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-athena

I'm trying to create an table in Athena via the AWS CLI. My file has string fields enclosed in quotes. my understanding is that I need to set the serdeproperties to take care of this. The below command doesn't work and I assume it has something to do with the way the way I handled escaping the quote in serdeproperties.

Doesn't work:

```
aws athena start-query-execution 
--query-string "
  create external table tbl1 (val1 INT, val2 STRING)
  ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' 
  WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('separatorChar' = ',', 'quoteChar' = '\"', 'escapeChar' = '\\')
  LOCATION 's3://bucketpath/folder'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1');"
--result-configuration "OutputLocation=s3://bucketpath/Output/"
```

Works:

```
aws athena start-query-execution 
--query-string "
  create external table tbl1 (val1 INT, val2 STRING)
  ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  LOCATION 's3://bucketpath/folder'
  TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1');"
--result-configuration "OutputLocation=s3://bucketpath/Output/"
```

Any thoughts?